# Resign Keyboard when Enter Key is Pressed in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have tried the following code but for some reason whenever I press the enter key on the keyboard, the keyboard does not resign. Why doesn't this work?

```
func trynaReturnKeyboard -> Bool {

       firstTextField.resignFirstResponder()
       secondTextField.resignFirstResponder()
       return true

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the textFieldDelegate and then use this code and assign the delegate self to you textfields in Viewdidload as

```
class yourClass: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {

func viewDidLoad(){

  super.viewDidLoad()
  firstTextField.delegate = self
  secondTextField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        firstTextField.resignFirstResponder()
       secondTextField.resignFirstResponder()
       return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to be a stickler, but in textFieldShouldReturn, it's fine to just resign the textField that was passed in. Resigning the responder for both text fields is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

1. you have to extend `UITextFieldDelegate`
2. give delegate to `UITextField`
3. Define `textFieldShouldReturn`

**Example**

```
firstTextField.delegate = self
firstTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done

secondTextField.delegate = self
secondTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 iOS SDK 11.0

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldReturn` to return `true`. Add the following code and assign your ViewController as delegate of the textfield.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```